# Mover las imágenes del servidor a una carpeta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

Hola quisiera saber como puedo mover la imagen que esta guardada en el servidor a una carpeta local en mi pc este es el código `

```
             <?php 

              if (isset($_POST['Enviar'])) {

                if (isset($_FILES['foto']['name'])) {
                  
                include ("configuracion/config.php");

                


                $tipoArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['type'];
                $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
                $tamanoArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['size'];
                $imagenSubida=fopen($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],'r');
                $binariosImagen=fread($imagenSubida,$tamanoArchivo);
                $binariosImagen=mysqli_escape_string($conexion,$binariosImagen);
               

                $conexion->query("INSERT INTO foto (Nombre,Foto,Tipo) values('$nombreArchivo','$binariosImagen',' $tipoArchivo')");

                
                header( "refresh:0.5; url=IniciarSesion.php" );

                }
              }   

            ?>
```

` y también me gustaría me de dieran sugerencias para mostrar la imagen

Answer (score 0):

En PHP hay una palabra reservada para realizar esta operacion.

Que es: `rename`

```
rename("carpetadonde esta el archivo/$_FILES['foto']['name']", "carpeta destino/$_FILES['foto']['name']");
```

Debes de tener claro la ruta del archivo que vas a mover.

Para mas informacion:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rename.php